# Можно ли установить соединение websocket в одном приложении, а послать сообщение из другого?

Tags: delphi, websocket

Приложение 1 установило соединение с клиентом по websocket, использую компонент sgcWebSocketServer. Когда я хочу послать сообщение клиенту. Из этого же приложения, делаю так `sgcWebSocketServer1.WriteData(wsAddress, 'сообщение');`

wsAddress беру при авторизации в

```
procedure TForm1.sgcWebSocketServer1Message(Connection: TsgcWSConnection;
  const Text: string);
begin
  wsAddress := Connection.Guid; // тип string
end;
```

Я храню этот адрес в базе, и хочу другим приложением взять адрес и послать по нему сообщение, это возможно? Если да, подскажите как, чет не выходит

Comment: websocket это позволяет. нужео хранить подключенных клиентов, и соотносить их ws-сессию с именем/адресом и отправлять сообщение по нужному подключению(сессии)

Comment: @Вадим,  расскажете немного подробнее?

Comment: как правило в базе хронят логин/пароль(либо хеш пароля). клиент при подключении к серверу должен пройти идентификацию-либо по http, либо сразу по ws. при этом создаётся однозначная связь между id сессией и логином/именем клиента. когда необходимо отправить сообщение нужному клиенту (как правило это задаётся именем/логином) происходит выбор в списке логин-сессия, по логину выбирают сесию и по конекшену этой сессии передают. при отключении - из списка удаляется пара логин-сессия. и соответственно передать ничего не возможно. как-то так, на самом простом уровне.

Comment: Никак это не сделать. Соединение устанавливает клиент. Сервер принимает соединение. Если "другое приложение" - это сервер, то отправить данные "не своему" клиенту оно не может. Потому что для отправки данных клиент должен сперва подключиться к этому другому приложению. А он (клиент) про него (другое приложение) ничего не знает и знать не должен.

Comment: @kami соглашусь, напрямую это сделать нельзя. но если есть база - то скорее всего есть сервер на котором развернут sgcWebSocketServer и через него можно посылать. вопрос: что есть "Приложкние 1" и что есть "клиент"? один из них, наверное, и несет функции sgcWebSocketServer.

Comment: Я всегда понимал это так, при подключении приложение **сервер** создает **соккет1**, на компьюторе, как и **клиент** свой **соккет2**. Сокеты знают друг о друге, а приложения знают каждый свои соккет, и если **на одном компе** запустить еще одно приложение **сервер2** и дать ему инфу о **соккете1**, то оно сможет так же общаться с клиентом. Вот если это так, я не пойму какие мне с моего компонента sgcWebSocketServer  нужно получить параметры что бы передать в sgcWebSocketServer другого приложения

Comment: не сможет. Информация о сокете (его handle) применима только в рамках процесса, в котором сокет создан. Даже второй экземпляр приложения ничего не сможет с ним сделать. Даже если это было бы возможно - информация не может идти по двум маршрутам в зависимости от вашего желания. На клиенте в любом случае будет только 1 сокет. И маршрут отправки данных через него известен - до сокета первого сервера.

Comment: @Вадим нет. Не напрямую тоже нельзя. Автор вопроса хочет послать с "левого" другого сервера данные клиенту, подключенному к первому серверу. Невозможно.

Comment: @ArtGrek13 вы можете реализовать обмен между основным сервером, который реализует вебсокеты и любым другим приложением посредством какого-нибудь способа IPC. Таким образом, сервер будет выступать промежуточным звеном общения между сторонним приложением и "клиентом". Получается вполне легальная и достаточно хорошая система взаимодействия

Comment: @kami мне интересен был именно этот способ, возможно или нет, я могу вторую пару сокетов сделать или вместо второго сервера создать клиента и через первый передать сообщение клиенту или объединить мои 2 серверных приложения в одно и общаться одной парой сокетов